# How to generate a file consisting of all scenarios tagged by @manual?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have a bunch of feature files. Some of scenarios and features are tagged with `@manual`. I'd want to generate a file that will contain all scenarios and features tagged with this tag so that it will be easier to find them out. Obviously I can write parser of feature files myself. But is there existing library or built in way that will do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing library to do it, but I would probably run

```
cucumber --tags @manual > manual.feature
```

Then open up "manual.feature" and remove the extra content!